# Knockout JS Binding and Filter Data

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following Problem

I have this Code to load Json Data from a external Web api
and Show it in my site  this works..

but my Problem is
I must FILTER the Data with a Dropdown List

When i select the Value "Show all Data" all my Data must be Show
and when i select the Value "KV" in the Dropdown only the Data
with the Text "KV" in the Object Arbeitsort must Show..

How can i integrate a Filter in my Code to Filter my Data over a Dropdown ?

and the next is how can i when i insert on each Item where in HTML Rendered a Button
to Show Details of this Item SHOWS his Detail Data ?

when i click Details in a Item i must open a Box and in this Box i must Show all Detail Data
of this specific Item ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function StellenangeboteViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.stellenangebote = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.Kat = ko.observable('KV');

    $.getJSON('http://api.domain.comn/api/Stellenangebot/', function (data) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.stellenangebote);
    });


}

ko.applyBindings(new StellenangeboteViewModel());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give this a go, but there's quite a few unknowns here. My suggestions are as follows:

First, create a `computed` for your results and bind to that instead of `self.stellenangebote`

```
self.stellenangeboteFiltered = ko.computed(function () {
    // Check the filter value - if no filter return all data
    if (self.Kat() == 'show all data') {
        return self.stellenangebote();
    }
    // otherwise we're filtering
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.stellenangebote(), function (item) {
        // filter the data for values that contain the filter term
        return item.Arbeitsort() == self.Kat();
    });
});
```

With regards the detail link, I'm assuming you are doing a `foreach` over your data in `self.stellenangeboteFiltered()`, so add a column to hold a link to show more details:

```
<table style="width:300px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Arbeitsort</th>
            <th>Details</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody data-bind="foreach: stellenangeboteFiltered">
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: Id"> </span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: Arbeitsort"> </span></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.showDetail">Detail</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Add a control to show details:

```
<div data-bind="visible: detailVisible, with: selectedItem">
    <span data-bind="text: Position"> </span>
    <span data-bind="text: Arbeitsort"> </span>
</div>
```

In your JS add a function:

```
// add some observables to track visibility of detail control and selected item
self.detailVisible = ko.observable(false);
self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

// function takes current row
self.showDetail= function(item){
    self.detailVisible(true);
    self.selectedItem(item);
};
```

**UPDATE**

Here's an updated fiddle: [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2LK6D/13/)

Comment: Hi Tanner 
I cannot reply an Answer ...

I Edit my Post befor with the Answer .....

Comment: @user3350113 i've updated the computed to to use a var called `filter` and the filter now searches for the term anywhere in the string. Note the use of `.toLowerCase` to avoid case conflict.

Comment: Hi Tanner,

with the new Code i become no Data, also not with the 'Show all Data' as Filter Keyword ....

when i delete the toLowerCase(); then Comes Data back
with the 'Show all Data' Keyword in the Filter, but the Filter
not works with any other Keyword....

can i send you the Link via Email to my Web api does you can test with the Original Data ??

Comment: did you change this comparison to be lowerecase: `filter == 'show all data'`?

Comment: yes with set the 'Show all data' to lowercase i become all data ...

but when i set the Filter to 'kv' no data Comes ....

Comment: @user3350113 do you get any console errors? If you create a working JSFiddle and I'll take a look, but difficult to diagnose without a working example.

Comment: @user3350113 have updated your fiddle to include required scripts: http://jsfiddle.net/2LK6D/7/ but not sure it can retrieve the data?

Comment: @user3350113 i've updated my post to include an updated fiddle, have removed the lower casing, which seemed to cause an issue to get it working.

Comment: Hi Tanner ,

Yes it works !!!
Thanks so much !!

Tanner can you please insert an Dropdown like
Show all Data - Show all Data
DemoText1 - KV
DemoText2 - M

and when i select a Item in the Dropdown does the Filter becomes the Data to Show the correct Group like KV or so ....

and another Little Question
when i become a Date back the Date Comes always as a American Date
with time...

how can i make this with Knockout and Binding Plugin
does i become the Date in German Format without Time
only the Date like this 12.12.2014 ???

Comment: Sorry I can't do all the work for you. If you have another question,  post it as a new question and reference this one.